# PDO error in PHP - " Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'could not find driver"

Tags: error-handling, pdo

I am using PDO to connect to database, but it returns this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'could not find driver' in C:\AppServ\www\php-learn\cms project\lib\database.class.php:19 Stack trace: #0 C:\AppServ\www\php-learn\cms project\lib\database.class.php(19): PDO->__construct('mysql://hostnam...', 'root', '00000') #1 C:\AppServ\www\php-learn\cms project\config.php(49): database::get_instance() #2 {main} thrown in C:\AppServ\www\php-learn\cms project\lib\database.class.php on line 19

#### File *database.class.php*:

```
class database
{
    // static  تستخدم عندما نريد استخدام الكلاس دون انشاء اوجيكت
    // () $ ! ~ & ^
    private static $db_connect;

    private function __construct()
    {} //

     // دالة لعمل اتصال ب قاعدة البيانتا

    // self ==> تشير الى اللاكلاس نفسة
    public static function get_instance()
    {
        if(null === self::$db_connect){

            self::$db_connect = new PDO
            ('mysql://hostname='.DB_HOST.';dbname=' . DB_NAME,
             DB_USER,
             DB_PASS);
        }
        return self::$db_connect;
    }

}
```

#### File *config.php*

```
// Start buffering  ==> the first function in the appliction
ob_start();
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT);
ini_set('register_globals', 0);
define("DS",DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
define("PS",PATH_SEPARATOR); // WINDOWS = ; , LUNIX = ,
define("HOST_NAME", 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/'); // DOMAIN NAME

// Paths
define("APP_PATH", realpath(dirname(__file__)) . DS);
define("TEMPLATE_PATH", APP_PATH . 'template' . DS);
define("LIB_PATH", APP_PATH . 'lib' . PS);

// Database
define("DB_HOST", "localhost");
define("DB_NAME", "cms_project");
define("DB_USER", "root");
define("DB_PASS", "00000");


$newpath = get_include_path() . PS . LIB_PATH; // Define new path
set_include_path($newpath);

function __autoload($class)
{
    require_once strtolower($class) . '.class.php';
}

$db_connect = database::get_instance();

// End the buffering
ob_flush();
```

Comment: the error is pretty self-explanatory: you don't have pdo_mysql ext installed. Also there should be no // slashes. And... you have too much useless code in your scripts.

Comment: One thought: In your php.ini uncomment lines `extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll` and `extension_dir = "ext"`. Ensure that the dll exists in ext directory